Blazor Landing Page from External Source with encrypted token
We are generating encrypted tokens for invitations sent to a user's email.  I need the user to be able to click on the link and land within my blazor app, have the token validated, and depending on the results either send the user through the Entra User Flow or send them to a 403 access denied.
The problem is that Blazor is just throwing a 404 any time someone tries to hit the page from the email.
Razor Markup
@page "/authentication/client/invitation/{token}"
@layout LandingPageLayout
@inherits BaseLandingPage
@rendermode InteractiveAuto

@if (ValidationResult.HasValue)
{
    if (ValidationResult == HMACResult.Valid)
    {
        <RedirectToEntraSignInComponent/>
    }
    else
    {
        <RedirectTo403Component />
    }
}

Razor code
public partial class ClientInvitationPage
{
    [Parameter]
    public string? Token { get; set; }

    [Inject] 
    public IClientDataBroker ClientDataBroker { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public ICurrentUserService CurrentUserService { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IConfigurationService ConfigurationService { get; set; }

    private HMACResult? ValidationResult { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

        var result = await ClientDataBroker.ValidateInvitationTokenAsync(Token);

        var tenantId = ConfigurationService.GetTenantId();

        if (string.Equals(tenantId, result.DecryptedToken?.EntraTenantId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            ValidationResult = result.ValidationResult;
        }
        else
        {
            //if the token does not belong to this tenant, reject
            ValidationResult = HMACResult.InvalidToken;
        }
    }
}


The first time the page renders [at var result = await ClientDataBroker.ValidateInvitationTokenAsync(Token);], ValidationResult will be null.  How's that handled in the page?

In the markup I have @if (ValidationResult.HasValue) protecting the logic

If var result = await ClientDataBroker.ValidateInvitationTokenAsync(Token); is a true async method, it will yield control before result is set.  The component will therefore render with ValidationResult as null - you can't test ValidationResult.HasValue on a null object.

If that's the case, then how am I supposed to get it to wait for a result?

Test for null or create an initial value for HMACResult with HasResult as false.  On the second render (after the component lifecycle methods complete) ValidationResult will not be null.
